# iPhone App Crashes when open from bit-ly link

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, bitly

I am facing this issue for multiple users. If app is already installed in the phone and then user tries to use bit-ly link to install the app, then app crashes on launch itself.

Tried finding solution but was not able to figure out the exact reason for the same.

Any suggestions will be of great help.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: can you please share the code - you used to handle `bit-ly` links?

Comment: Actually I have only used applinks and no handling is done for bit-ly links.

Comment: are you able to debug it?

Comment: We are not using bitly SDK to handle the app launch. As i was going through the bitly SDK, it needs to be integrated in the project and predefined bitly function handles the bitly json for app launch. I just have one question now - So in order to install app using bitly, integrating bit-ly SDK is must?

Comment: no idea. haven't worked on billy SDK

Comment: So what kind of crash it is? Did you use some crash report system like crashlytics? Our you can symbolicate crashes with appstoreconnect & xcode

Comment: @MikhailVasilev Yes we have integrated Crashlytics and it crash log gives  AppDelegate.application(_:continue:restorationHandler:) + 4306323820 in this method.

Comment: @harshvikramsingh And so, what is the code inside "AppDelegate continue userActivity" ?

Comment: @MikhailVasilev I am not doing any specific handling for bitly in my continue userActivity method. It is just handling the applink launch. Previously as per SDK used "Bitly.handle(userActivity)" this method in my continue userActivity method. But with no success.